# GNN Permutation Invariance to Input Data?

Tags: graph, deep-learning, permutation, pytorch-geometric

I have a problem regarding permutation invariance and equivariance of graph neural networks. In my setting I have a set of nodes that is connected via a set of edges. I would like to predict binary classes wrt. the nodes, e.g., the label is a vector of zeros and ones.

During the graph construction stage I basically stack "positive" and "negative" nodes on top of each other in an unsorted manner under the assumption that the GNN is permutation-equivariant. Thus the node feature matrix is: [X_p, X_n]^T. So as long as the label vector is permuted the same way it should work out fine under permutation equivariance.

However, I found out that my prediction accuracy drops massively as soon as I shuffle the node feature matrix (similarly the label vector). This leads my to the interpretation that the naive stacking operation eased the learning problem.

All operations that the GNN performed were MLPs (X*W), ReLU, neighborhood aggregation sums, Sigmoid or taking advantage of node connectivity via the adjacency matrix (edge_index in torch_geometric). Thus, there would be no way how the node ordering could influence the learning outcome because all operations are permutation-invariant. Nonetheless, the opposite occurs.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you very much!

Comment: If you shuffled the node's, did you also generated the new edge index? Or did you still used the old edges? If it's the loose the information, which is "contained" in the graph, e.g. assortative neighbourhoods.